# Numpy: set one specific element of each column based on indexing by array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

On a smaller scale compared to what I need, here's an example of what I'm looking to do:

```
>>> a
array([[  21,   22,   23,   24,   25,   26,   27],
       [  56,   57,   58,   59,   60,   61,   62],
       [  14,   15,   16,   17,   18,   19,   20],
       [   7,    8,    9, 1010,   11,   12,   13],
       [  42,   43,   44,   45,   46,   47,   48],
       [  63,   64,   65,   66,   67,   68,   69],
       [   0,    1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6],
       [  49,   50,   51,   52,   53,   54,   55],
       [  28,   29,   30,   31,   32,   33,   34],
       [  35,   36,   37,   38,   39,   40,   41]])
>>> indices = a.argmax(axis=0)
>>> indices
array([5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5])
>>> b = np.zeros(a.shape)
>>> b[indices] = 1.0
>>> b # below is the actual output, not what I want
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

But what I actually need is:

```
>>> b
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Numpy indexing can get extremely complicated and it's a little difficult to put the above into words, so hopefully someone can understand what I'm looking for. Essentially it's to set a 1 wherever there's a max of a column and zero elsewhere. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

> If the number of objects in the selection tuple is less than N , then
>   `:` is assumed for any subsequent dimensions.

In your selection there only one array, so you get every row from indices to be equal to 1. To overcome that, you need column indices. I guess this will do the trick:

```
b[indices, np.arange(a.shape[1])] = 1.0
```

Comment: nice :-) i knew there was a one-liner somewhere

Comment: Aha, thanks! I feel like I understand numpy indexing a little better now.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I come from MATLAB, so doing `0:a.shape[1]` I thought would actually produce the column indices but this performs slicing.  In MATLAB, the `:` operator does both slicing and generate a vector of indices so that was where my trouble came from.  Now I know that I have to manually produce the column indices.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There might be a way without a loop but you can always do:

```
indices = a.argmax(axis=0)
b = np.zeros(a.shape)
for j,ind in enumerate(indices):
    b[ind, j] = 1
```