# Scipy sparse array from list of integers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have a list (actually, a  panda Series) of integers which I want to turn into a sparse matrix for which row `i` has only one non zero value at `j` the index defined by the `i`th element of the list. A little bit like in the question : [Numpy: set one specific element of each column based on indexing by array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816117/numpy-set-one-specific-element-of-each-column-based-on-indexing-by-array)

For now I am first turning the data in a dense matrix, like this :

```
def cat_to_mat(c, mat_length):
    res = np.zeros((len(c), mat_length))
    res[np.arange(len(c)), c.values % mat_length] = 1
    return res
```

and then I call `csr_matrix` on the resulting array. However, it seems a waste to generate a dense matrix and throw away most of its elements.

I am aware of tools like `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder` but they do not really suit because I would like to avoid calling the `fit()` method: I want to be sure that the (sparse) representation of the data will only depend on `c` and `mat_length` (and not on some previous data provided to the `OneHotEncoder`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems rather straightforward. Did I misunderstand the question?

```
from scipy import sparse

def cat_to_mat(c, mat_length):
    return sparse.csc_matrix((c, (len(c), c % mat_length)), shape=(len(c), mat_length))
```

Comment: No this is perfectly fine, I am not familiar with the constructors of these matrices... I should have started there, thanks :)